# WCF service as remote agent

Tags: wcf, security, distributed

I am building a distributed system. It will contain one managment console and many remote agents (WCF services). How to provide secure communications between managment console and agents in non domain network?

Answer (score 0):

run the WCF connections over HTTPS

Comment: WCF connections over HTTPS make it possible authenticate agent (i.e. host WCF) and secure traffic. How to create authenticate the managment console on agent side (many agents, one console)?

Comment: take a look at this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx it talks about using certificates to authenticate WCF channels, you can also use username/passwords in a similar way to that which you would with an ASP.Net application